# Android: Redmi note 5 pro (Android 9) aborting the API connection through wifi access point network

Tags: android, android-wifi

I have API to fetch details which does not need any internet connection(through access network). It will give immediate response in all device except in Redmi Note 5 pro with android version 9. It will give response sometimes but it will take around 2 mins.

Comment: Have you added _android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"_  in your manifest file?

Comment: Yes added. But it is causing for only local access point network that too with only android 9 version. In chrome also it is taking more than 2 minutes to connect. But in app it will through connection abort exception for android 9 version and for other OS it is immediate response